# Shopify API, unable to create order

Tags: api, rest, e-commerce, shopify

I created private application on my test shop and I am trying to create simple order via the Shopify API following the instructions found here:

http://docs.shopify.com/api/order#create

I am using the last example, and sending POST request to admin/orders.json with this in the body of the request:

```
{
  "order": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "variant_id": 500775053
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

500775053 is a **valid** variant id.

The response I'm getting is:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "line_items": [
            "must have at least one line item"
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong? Is there some special parameter that I should pass along the request? Some special header?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these custom headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```