# using shopify api with .net post requests on a private app

Tags: c#, .net, rest, shopify

has anybody got a . net example  of running a simple post to the shopify create order Ive seen some really old examples but they dont seem to work the ones that do answer have  no code examples im trying the following but just get bad request back, surely this should be simple?

```
private static async Task runShopifyAsyncCreateOrderJsonTask()
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = GetCredential() })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

           string json = @"{'order': {'line_items': [{'variant_id': 720123393,'quantity': 1}]}}";

            // HTTP post
            HttpResponseMessage response = await     client.PostAsJsonAsync("admin/orders.json", test);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Uri uri = response.Headers.Location;
                var results = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ive looked at the following but it does not show the code :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426321/shopify-api-unable-to-create-order

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but in case someone comes across it check out these classes:
[ShopifyApi.cs](https://github.com/ibliskavka/sharepoint-bcs-shopify/blob/master/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify/ShopifyApi.cs), [ShopifyClient.cs](https://github.com/ibliskavka/sharepoint-bcs-shopify/blob/master/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify/ShopifyClient.cs), [Program.cs](https://github.com/ibliskavka/sharepoint-bcs-shopify/blob/master/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify/Ibliskavka.SharePoint.Bcs.Shopify.TestConsole/Program.cs). It uses WebClient which might be a little easier to use but still gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around I found this works:

```
        string ShopPath = "/admin/api/2020-04/";
        string shopifyAddProduct = "products.json";
        string shopifyGetProductFmt = "products.json?title={0}";
        string URL = String.Format("https://{0}.myshopify.com{1}", ShopName, ShopPath);
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(APIkey/*username*/, APIpass/*Password*/),
            PreAuthenticate = true
        };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // need an access token...
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", APIpass);

        var shopify = new
        {
            product = new
            {
                title = "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
                body_html = "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
                vendor = "Snowboard",
                product_type = "Snowboard",
                published = false
            }
        };

        // before we try and add a product, we should query if we already have it?
        string shopifyGetProduct = String.Format(shopifyGetProductFmt, Uri.EscapeUriString(shopify.product.title));
        HttpResponseMessage getResponse = client.GetAsync(shopifyGetProduct).Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
        if (getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            bool foundProduct;
            foundProduct = false;
            // Parse the response body.
            GetProducts curProduct = getResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<GetProducts>().Result;  //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
            if (curProduct != null)
            {
                foreach (var cp in curProduct.products)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found id: {0}", cp.id);
                    foundProduct = true;
                }
            }
            if (!foundProduct)
            {

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(shopifyAddProduct, shopify).Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body.
                    AddProducts newProduct = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AddProducts>().Result;  //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
                    if ((newProduct != null) && (newProduct.product != null))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("new id: {0}", newProduct.product.id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)getResponse.StatusCode, getResponse.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        //Dispose once all HttpClient calls are complete. This is not necessary if the containing object will be disposed of; for example in this case the HttpClient instance will be disposed automatically when the application terminates so the following call is superfluous.
        client.Dispose();
```

No the code is not really asynchronous - I'll leave that to you to work out - I'm demonstrating how to use HttpClient with Shopify, not demonstrating how to write asynchronous code.

The AddProduct class can be generated by pasting the returned JSON into visual studio with 'paste special'.  However the 'Root' classes are a bit difficult, so I'll paste them here:

```
public class AddProducts
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class GetProducts
{
    public Product[] products { get; set; }
}
```

Good luck!